# Tic Tac Toe AI issue in C

Tags: c, random, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I tried making a simple tic tac toe project, and I am trying to make the AI move to random places, so that the AI just moves into any available place.  However, it always makes 2 moves.  I am wondering why it always makes 2 moves instead of just 1.

What I mean is, let's say the user inputs 'O' into slot 1,1.

```
     0    1    2
  +----+----+----+
0 |    |    |    |
  |    |    |    |
  +----+----+----+
  |    |    |    |
1 |    |  O |    |
  +----+----+----+
  |    |    |    |
2 |    |    |    |
  +---------------
```

Then the computer moves 2 moves: into slots 1,2 AND 2,0

```
     0    1    2
  +----+----+----+
0 |    |    |    |
  |    |    |    |
  +----+----+----+
  |    |    |    |
1 |    |  O | X  |
  +----+----+----+
  |    |    |    |
2 |  X |    |    |
  +---------------
```

So I'd like to know why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
void compMove(char board[][columns])
{
     int randomNum, randomNum1, i, j;
     bool didMove = FALSE;

     srand((int)time(NULL));         //Seed the random number generator
     randomNum = rand() % 3;
     randomNum1 = rand() % 3;
     while(board[randomNum][randomNum1] != ' ')
     {
               randomNum = rand() % 3;
               randomNum1 = rand() % 3;                                   
     }
     for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
               for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
               {
                     if(i == randomNum && j == randomNum1)
                     {
                            board[i][j] = 'X';          
                            didMove = TRUE;
                            break;
                     }
               }
               if(didMove == TRUE)           break;
     }               
}
```

Comment: To start with, *don't* seed the random number generator more than once. I recommend you do it as early as possible in the `main` function, and not do it again.

Comment: Show us the code that calls `compMove`, looks like there are no errors in this function. The likely hood is you are calling `compMove` twice.

Comment: How does `board[]` get initialized (before being passed to `compMove()`)?

Comment: Also, how, where and when do you call your `compMove` function? It might be called twice?

Comment: Just a quick comment on one particular instance of good style: instead of _if(didMove == TRUE)_, you can directly use _if(didMove)_. This is generally considered good style.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop to set movement on the board.

```
board[randomNum][randomNum1] = 'X';
```

is enough to set.

And you probably call this function twice, because function plays only one move.

Comment: Please see the edit, and see if there's something wrong where I call the function

Comment: It seems like it should work correctly. All I can think of is either checkWin() function calls compMove() or after computer plays(when i equals to 1), userMove() function skips without receiving an input(when i equals to 2) and computer plays again(i equals to 3). You may try to debug and see if this is the case.

Comment: I dont think either of those are the problems, thanks for the help though.  Any other possible problems you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `checkWin` function is the culprit. Probably has an `=` somewhere you meant to have an `==`. But that's just a guess without seeing it.

Your `compMove` function is grossly overcomplicated, but not wrong. Here's code that does the same thing:

```
void compMove(char board[][columns]) {
    int row, col;
    /* DON'T seed RNG here; do it once in main() */
    do {
        row = rand() % 3;
        col = rand() % 3;
    } while (board[row][col] != ' ');
    board[row][col] = 'X';
}
```

Comment: thanks, i've made it simpler, however checkWin is not the culprit

Comment: Then either `dispBoard` is the only possibility, or else the code you're running isn't the code posted here.